# How to print all inbox emails

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, imap, ports

I am pretty new to Java and know nothing about ports or servers or sockets so i was hoping someone could help me. I want to make a little program that will print all the messages in your inbox (read and unread).

I found this code online but it only gives me my earliest message in my sent folder.

```
public class EmailService {
  String server = "pop.gmail.com";
  int port = 995;
  static String username;
  static String password;

  SSLSocket socket;
  BufferedReader input;
  PrintWriter output;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      username = s.next() + "@gmail.com";
      password = s.next();
      new EmailService();
  }

  public EmailService() {
    try {
        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        socket = (SSLSocket)sslsocketfactory.createSocket(server, port);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        // After each println you MUST flush the buffer, or it won't work properly.
        // The true argument makes an automatic flush after each println.
        output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
        connect();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void connect() throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Greeting message: ");
    String response = readOneLine();
    System.out.println(response);

    // Username
    output.println("USER " + username);
    response = readOneLine();
    System.out.println(response);

    // Password
    output.println("PASS " + password);
    response = readOneLine();
    System.out.println(response);

    output.println("RETR 1");
    while (!response.equals(".")) {
        response = readOneLine();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
  }

  public String readOneLine() throws IOException {
    return input.readLine();
  }
}
```

How would I change this code to get me all the messages in my inbox?

Comment: No need to write this kind of low-level code. Use the JavaMail library instead.

Comment: Dnault had a good idea for you. [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) is pretty efficient. Network Solutions has been using it for years to spam me and millions of others. They are not the smartest bunch (they could not stop even after I sued them), so it must be easy to use, too.